# Ansible playbook convert bytes to GB

Tags: ansible

I believe I will get the solution over here.
I have a Variable volumes output below here which has vol_size key value having number in bytes,
How can I get output in GB for the same output.

```
ok: [localhost] =>
  volumes:
    cluster1.demo.netapp.com:
    - id: cluster1_vol1
      svm: svm1
      volume_size: '1073741824'
    - id: cluster1_vol3
      svm: svm1
      volume_size: '2147483648'
    - id: silas_vol
      svm: svm1
      volume_size: '10737418240'
    - id: engineering
      svm: svm1
      volume_size: '10737418240'
    cluster2.demo.netapp.com:
    - id: cluster2_vol1
      svm: svm5
      volume_size: '1073741824'
    - id: cluster2_vol3
      svm: svm5
      volume_size: '2147483648'
    - id: shoreview_vol
      svm: svm5
      volume_size: '10737418240'
```

Comment: There is a filter for that: [`human_readable`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#human-readable)